# Using Bresenham's circle algorithm (or another alternative algorithm) to draw an arc

Tags: graphics, z80, assembly, zx-spectrum

I'm trying to create some graphics function for a ZX Spectrum (Z80) machine in assembler. I already have the basics except for the arc.

I know that there must be some way to draw an arc using the Bresenham's circle algorithm but I'm unable to find concrete info about it, there are sentences like "set the pixels only if they fall into the wanted interval" but I have no clue on how to determine if the pixels fall within it.

As data I have the circle's center and radius and the start and end points of the arc in the circle, I only miss how to determine if a pixel lies in the arc, if the algorithm were completely linear (start at 0º and sweep to 360º) it would be easy to do not draw until the start point is reached and then continue drawing until the last point is reached, but the Bresenham's algorithm is drawn in octants simultaneously so I have no idea on how to do it.

I'm not tied to anything so any other algorithm would be welcome, no need to be specifically for the spectrum, just any assembler algorithm to draw an arc will be enough, even if I need different info (like the three point arc algorithm).

Cheers.

Comment: As far as I remember, the main benefits of Bresenham's circle algorithm are the "octal symmetry of a circle", and the fact you can implement it with integer math only. I cannot figure any easy (and yet generic) way to constraint the drawing algorithm by start and end angle. Did you try to implement Bézier curves? (But they requires a lot of multiplying...)

Comment: @MartinMaly I don't have the start and end angles but the start and end points in the circle, using angles I could easily test if the pixel lies within the range by it's angle using the arc tangent, but that would mean to use floating point operations and that's a performance killer and increases the complexity a lot.
About bezier... I haven't found any implementation, do you know any? If it's not too slow it would be more than enough for my purposes.

Comment: @MartinMaly: They require no multiplies or divides, at least not in the loop. The symmetry is an extra bonus that you would either ditch, or would complicate it for an arc.

Comment: @Gusman: I was about to ask if you really meant you had the points and not the angles. Bresenham works with centre and radius and to extend it to arcs you would need start and end angle in radians. So you have to first normalize from the points you have to angles. I never implemented that but it will be in graphics books or collections of algrorithms or formulae.

Comment: @hippietrail Yes, I could convert the points to angles and then check if each point I'm going to draw is between these angles, but then I would need to use floating point operations and I'm trying to avoid that, too complex and slow...

Comment: @Wilson I am using the ROM function from assembler but it's painfully slow, the implementation in the Spectrum ROM uses the calculator stack to compute the arc using internally a lot of floating point operations and that's what i'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Wilson: The Spectrum's Basic circle-drawing algorithm does not use Breseham's algorithm. They seem not to have been aware of it. The use a much slower method resulting in much more lumpy circles that I assume is based on the ROM's trig functions.

Comment: @Gusman: Back in the day we used to used fixed point. In any case you only have to calculate that stuff once per arc, not once for every point. I also used to use power-of-two steps with 0 representing 0 or -pi and 255 representing pi or 2pi. You can also do lookup tables using the same power of two number of entries. It's 25 to 30 years since I played with that stuff though and I never did arcs. The better you grok trig the better you can manage. Try a graphics forum.

Comment: @hippietrail Yeah, the arc seems to be somewhat a cursed topic, there is none to little information and the one that I can find is very limited... I will try a graphics forum, thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Gusman since this isn't retro-specific and it's already getting negative votes I'm going to suggest it get moved to [computergraphics SE](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/). Tweak your wording to ask for an integer or fixed-point solution. Note that two circles (or none) will satisfy crossing through two points with a given radius.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bresenhams-circle-drawing-algorithm/

Comment: you can exploit `x^2+y^2=r` and dot product with arc start/end... so no floating point and no goniometrics... see [Is there a more efficient way of texturing a circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61097673/2521214) and [Generate a “pieslice” in C without using the pieslice() of graphics.h](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58246614/2521214) for some ideas you can do this just by `+,-` operations (`*,sqrt`) can be avoided. Back in the days we used precomputed 256 Byte aproximation of `sin` table (computed by single loop and IIRC only `+/-,++,--` operations. But that was before I learned math...

Comment: @Spektre Thanks a lot for the info, I will take a look at it.

Comment: @Gusman aaah I got a typo it should be `x^2+y^2=r^2` of coarse  :) for non filed stuff you simply do `x = sqrt(r*r-y*y)` or `y = sqrt(r*r-x*x)` inside single `for` loop (according to `dx<=dy` slope) where x or y is incrementing or decrementing so you can avoid higher operations (`^2` , `sqrt`) with the tricks from the links... for 8 bit coordinates the `sqrt` is just 8 iterations on 16 bit values. Also you should have optimized pixel access my best I ever done (as rookie) was IIRC `143T` per `pixel(x,y)`.... but I am confident I would do better now

Comment: As my multi-field knowledge gives me sometimes crazy ideas that usually really pay off with high performance in comparison to standard methods. btw I think this question is a worthy one for [SO/SE](https://stackoverflow.com) (I would be happy to try to code something like that in C++  with limitations to basic math operators and 8/16 bit integers)

Comment: We wrote a system that hand to effectively draw circles on a Z80.  We had the advantage of a pair of fixed radii.  What we did was encode 45 degrees of each of the two circles using a simple compass point algorithm. If you can draw 45 deg, you can draw a whole circle (by exchanging sin and cos, and by flipping signs).  We stored the "next point" in the circle as one of 8 cardinal (N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW), putting two of them in each byte.  Then we just walked around the circle.  It was lightening fast (well, for a Z80).

Comment: @Flydog57 heh something similar was used for driving CNC tools along curves (at my work) before "real" interpolation was implemented. only 8 directions where used ...

Answer (score 2):

There might be many options, but you need to calculate if you should draw a pixel or not. When you define an arc say from 10 to 100 degrees, you have two endpoints that lie on a circle. Based on radius and angle, you can calculate the X and Y coordinates of these two endpoints. You can imagine drawing a line between these two points, and if the circle pixel is above the line, the pixels get drawn, otherwise they are not. So whe you draw the circle with Breseham's you get X,Y coordinates and for the X you calculate the Y coordinate of the line and if Y of arc is >= Y of line then plot.

Comment: I already have those points as stated on the question, and that method does not work, if I have start point at 0º and end point at 180º ({ x:0, y:Radius}, { x:0, y:-Radius}) that will create a virtual line from top to bottom, so it would draw the full circle instead of half.

Comment: Yes, special cases need to be handled, just like when drawing a line with Bresenham along Y or along X axis. Flip the coordinate axes when line has X1==X2, you need it anyway for all arcs. I just got confused as usually the coordinates for 0° is y=0 x=radius.

Comment: Something tells me that this would fail in many cases but I'm going to test it

Comment: Yep, this doesn't works at all, check this image, it will explain better why this can't work.
https://imgur.com/a/y4btej9

Comment: Well obviously, because the straight line must go between points A and B. Everything that is below/left of the line between A and B is the arc.

Comment: Even in that case it would cut the bottom of the arc...

Comment: But you need to determine if you must draw pixels below or above the line, depending on the arc angles.

Comment: If I use angles then I have no need to check X or Y, just the angle, and I'm trying to avoid to use floating point ops, that's a killer for a Z80.